# Firebase user's details change listener in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

so if a user logs into your app, you can check that by

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{});
```

but if the user is already logged in and his user has a property change, how do you see that?

in my case, I have the user verify his email address and when done, he should be able to see a change instantly on his app after verifying his email. So I am using react native, which is pretty much javascript with ES6 syntax in it and I am doing a `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged();` but its not working, I even have a button on the screen that checks if verified like this:

```
if (!firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified) { firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification(); }
else if (firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified) { this.setState({ showVerifier: false }); }
```

but even that isn't working, as if the `firebase.auth().currentUser` doesn't update if the email is verified, what can be done here?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, I would like to give you an idea. 
I think `onAuthStateChanged()` gets triggered only when your Auth State Changes (login, logout) and not when the user properties change. 
As they have mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged),

> Adds an observer for changes to the user's sign-in state. Prior to
> 4.0.0, this triggered the observer when users were signed in, signed out, or when the user's ID token changed in situations such as token
> expiry or password change. After 4.0.0, the observer is only triggered
> on sign-in or sign-out.

```
function isVerified(){
   var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   if(user != null){
       var status = user.emailVerified;
       if(status)
       {
          // Verified
       }else{
          // Not Verified
       }
   }
   else{
       // User didn't login!
   } 
}
```

So, you have to manually check it by defining a function like above and you can call this function when the user clicks the button

Comment: It doesn't work, the state of the existing user doesn't changes. Its user.emailVerified doesn't change even after calling `firebase.auth().currentUser`. I did the same thing in my question, you just wrote it in a more expanded manner with use of vars, I tried that, its the same thing and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-native-firebase` (highly recommended, since it is supports the latest firebase features), you can listen on user changes as stated in [this doc](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth#onUserChanged)

From the doc

> Adds a listener to observe changes to the User object. This is a superset of everything from `auth#onAuthStateChanged`, `auth#onIdTokenChanged` and user changes. The goal of this method is to provide easier listening to all user changes, such as when credentials are linked and unlinked, without manually having to call `User#reload`.

```
onUserChanged(listener: AuthListenerCallback): () => void;
```

Comment: `react-native-firebase` is a wrapper for  firebase right? so if the actual firebase's listener doesn't update on email verification, will the `react-native-firebase` listener catch it? doesn't make sense

Comment: Yes it is, but as mentioned in the doc its not just a wrapper for `onAuthStateChanged` method of `firebase`. Which library are you using? Have you tried implementing the above method?